# How do i delete items from a list in python

Tags: python, list

I try to delete items from a list , from the initial position to a final position:

```
def remove_range(s,f):   #this is the function 
    for i in range(s, f):
    del numbers[i]

#and this is in the main:
if cmd.startswith("remove items"):
    try:
        n = input("")
        m = input("")
        int(n)
        int(m)
        remove_range(n, m)
```

Why this function doesn't work?

Comment: not necessarily n-1 or m-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting an item shifts the following list items up 1. Supposing you have 10 items and delete 3, 4, 5. What really happens is that on deleting 3, 4 and following shift up one. When you then delete 4, you are really deleting the original 5. Fortunately list slicing solves the problem

```
del numbers[s:f]
```

Comment: That's not a list comprehension.

Comment: hmmm... I've always considered slicing to be part of list comprehensions. I'll change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this notation

```
del numbers[s:f]
```